# How can I delete a document that I use for unit testing with Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is what I have in test_helper.js

```
const mongoose =  require('mongoose');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

before((done) => {
    mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://Minh:111g@testschedulingdb-dt089t.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true', { useNewUrlParser: true });
    mongoose.connection
        .once('open', () => { done(); })
        .on('error', (error) => {
         console.warn('Warning', error);
    });
});

beforeEach((done) => {
    mongoose.connection.collections.requests.drop(() => {
        done();
    });
});
```

As you see, I drop an entire collection before starting a new test. How can I remove only a document used for testing? I tried this but it doesn't right

```
beforeEach((done) => {
    mongoose.connection.collections.requests.remove((name: 'Minh') => {
        done();
    });
```

Comment: Try .remove({name: 'Minh'}, (err) => {})?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.remove() function can't be null, you need to pass an object to it, which can be empty or have a filter, if it's empty it will remove all data from that collection and if there is a filter, it will remove only that element

```
 mongoose.connection.collections.requests.remove({'name' :'Minh'},(err) => {
    done();
});
```

or if you want to remove all data then,

```
mongoose.connection.collections.requests.remove({},(err) => {
    done();
});
```